# How do I show just the names and commit titles since a tag in Git?

Tags: git, git-log

I'm trying to use tags for release management in Git—I create a tag for each release. I'd like to be able to create release notes by listing the comment titles for every commit since a tag, or between 2 tags. I can't seem to find any way to do this.

Answer (score 91, accepted):

If your tags are named `LastRelease` and `NextRelease` then do

`git log --pretty=format:%s LastRelease..NextRelease`
.

Comment: Awesome tip; I could never figure out how to get `git log` to only show partial information. Thank you!

Comment: You can also use `git log --oneline` which prints the title and part of the hash.

Comment: Additionally, if you want to list all of the commit titles from the start of a branch, you can use `previous_branch_name..HEAD` instead of `LastRelease..NextRelease`.

Answer (score 39):

To show commits since TAG to current head:

```
git log TAG..HEAD
```

Between two commits:

```
git log TAG..TAG
```

For formatting the log output have a look at [Pretty formats section of git log](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-log#_pretty_formats).

Comment: This lists more than just titles. See my answer.

Answer (score 13):

You should look into `git shortlog`. Here's an example of the output:

```
$ git shortlog
Al Jones (512):
      Added to .gitignore file
      Updated user model

Bob Smith (222):
      Minor tweak to view
      Updated accounts controller

Charles West (321):
      Started specs for user model
      Finished specs for user model
```

For your case you would want to run `git shortlog LastRelease..NextRelease`

Answer (score 4):

I combined Dominic's and Igor's answers together to return the titles of all commits from 2b150c4 to the current HEAD in chronological order and prints it to Terminal (`echo` added because `git log` doesn't line break the last line).

```
git log --pretty=format:%s 2b150c4..HEAD --reverse | cat; echo
```

Answer (score 2):

In order to get detailed infos on commit with a certain (known) message, I firstly call `git log --oneline` for overview of commints with messeges and then by the identified SHA view the commit  with `git show <SHA>` or `git log --stat -p  <SHA>`