# Using GIT hooks to modify release notes

Tags: git, githooks

We have a GIT repository with many contributors, and we constantly run into merge conflicts with the release notes file. Is there a good way to prevent them?

I was thinking of a git post-upload server hook that would run run on master branch only, and use a script to extract some magic keyword from the commit message and append following text to the release notes file. Are there any tools for that? Is that a good approach?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if there is such a tool, but if you need to attach information on a particular commit, I would recommend using **[`git notes`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9856913/6309)**, in order to not modify the SHA1.

You could add information like the one suggested in "[How do I show just the names and commit titles since a tag in git?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2941614/6309)".

Any automated processing of said commit messages supposes they are following a strict format (like [that article illustrates](http://tbaggery.com/2008/04/19/a-note-about-git-commit-messages.html)), which should then be enforced by a *pre*-commit hook (or at least one `pre-receive` hook on the remote side).